# Удаление записей MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Имеется следующий код:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($databaseserver, $databaseusername, $databasepassword, $databasename);
if(!$mysqli){
    die("ОШИБКА ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ К БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ.");
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM QUESTIONARY_ADMIN ORDER by ID DESC";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s %s", 'НОМЕР АНКЕТЫ: ', $row["ID"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'ДАТА И ВРЕМЯ ОТПРАВКИ: ',$row["DATE_TIME_UTC"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'STEAMID64: ', $row["USERSTEAMID64"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'DISCORD: ',$row["USERDISCORD"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'ВОЗРАСТ: ',$row["USERAGE"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'КОЛИЧЕСТВО ЧАСОВ В ИГРЕ UNTURNED: ',$row["USERGAMETIMEUNTURNED"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'КОЛИЧЕСТВО ЧАСОВ В ДЕНЬ, КОТОРОЕ ГОТОВ(А) УДЕЛЯТЬ ПРОЕКТУ: ',$row["USERFORPROJECTTIME"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'ПОЛ: ',$row["USERGENDER"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'ЗНАНИЕ ПРАВИЛ: ',$row["USERKNOWRULES"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'НАЛИЧИЕ МИКРОФОНА: ',$row["USERHAVEMICROPHONE"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'УМЕНИЕ ПРОВЕРЯТЬ ИГРОКОВ НА НАЛИЧИЕ СТОРОННЕГО ПРОГРАММНОГО ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЯ: ',$row["USERCANCHECKCHEATS"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s", 'НАЛИЧИЕ ОПЫТА АДМИНИСТРИРОВАНИЯ: ',$row["USERADMINEXPERIENCE"]);
        printf ("<br>%s %s<br><br>", 'ЗНАНИЕ КОМАНД, ДОСТУПНЫХ ЧЛЕНАМ АДМИНИСТРАЦИИ: ',$row["USERKNOWADMINCOMMANDS"]);
    }
    $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Он выводит данные из базы данных. 
Каждая "АНКЕТА" является одной строкой. 
Сейчас решил сделать возможность удаления, но немного не понимаю как это сделать, так как нужно сделать удаление для каждой анкеты отдельно, чтобы после каждой "АНКЕТЫ" была кнопка "УДАЛИТЬ".

Answer (score -2):

```
print ('<br /><a href="/api.php?action=rm&id='.$row["ID"].'">[УДАЛИТЬ АНКЕТУ]</a>');
```

Вариант с кнопкой без Javascript

```
print('<br /><form action="/api.php" method="POST">'.
    '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row["ID"].'" />'.
    '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="rm" />'.
    '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Удалить" />'.
'</form>');
```

В `/api.php` проверяете GET-параметры (для примера кнопки - POST) и удаляете запись через [MySQL DELETE](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DELETE.html).
При доступе к этому URL не забудьте проверить права у пользователя, который пытается удалить анкету.

Вместо `/api.php` можете использовать любой путь, по которому будет размещен код для удаления строки из базы.

Comment: А возможно ли это сделать без API? Имею ввиду, чтобы всё было в одном документе.

Comment: Вы можете передавать параметры хоть текущей странице, но с точки зрения организации кода это не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: Добавил пример с кнопкой вместо ссылки. Можно еще ajax'ом, но это уже надо код JavaScript добавлять